# modify centos firewalld zone file with augeas loses indentation

Tags: xml, puppet, augeas, firewalld

I'm trying to modify a centos firewalld zone file using augeas and the xml lens.

The default public zone file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <short>Public</short>
  <description>For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
  <service name="dhcpv6-client"/>
  <service name="ssh"/>
</zone>
```

and if I load that into augtool I get the following:

```
# augtool --noload --noautoload --echo
augtool> set /augeas/load/xml/lens "Xml.lns"
augtool> set /augeas/load/xml/incl "/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml"
augtool> load
augtool> print /files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/#declaration
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/#declaration/#attribute
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/#declaration/#attribute/version = "1.0"
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/#declaration/#attribute/encoding = "utf-8"
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone/#text[1] = "\n  "
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone/short
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone/short/#text = "Public"
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone/#text[2] = "  "
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone/description
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone/description/#text = "For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted."
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone/#text[3] = "  "
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone/service[1] = "#empty"
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone/service[1]/#attribute
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone/service[1]/#attribute/name = "dhcpv6-client"
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone/#text[4] = "  "
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone/service[2] = "#empty"
/files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone/service[2]/#attribute
```

I then try

```
augtool> defnode service /files/etc/firewalld/zones/public.xml/zone/service[attribute/#name="http"]
augtool> set $service "#empty"
augtool> set $service/#attribute/name "http"
augtool> save
```

and if I now look at the public.xml file, it looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <short>Public</short>
  <description>For use in public areas. You do not trust the other computers on networks to not harm your computer. Only selected incoming connections are accepted.</description>
  <service name="dhcpv6-client"/>
  <service name="ssh"/>
<service name="http"/>
</zone>
```

Can anyone suggest how I could preserve the indentation before the `<service name="http">` entry that I added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to keep the indentation when adding a new node with Augeas.